# Insert Query doesn't save data to the database

Tags: c#, insert, ado.net

After clicking on the button on the add form, the row is added to the table. But when I restart the program it is not there.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddIn add = new AddIn();

        if (add.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {          
  
        documentTableAdapter1.InsertQuery(Convert.ToInt32(add.tb_num.Text),add.data_pic.Value, add.tb_cx.Text, false, Convert.ToInt32(add.tb_pag.Text), null,true, null, 5, false);
 
            dataGridView1.DataSource = inTableAdapter.GetData();
            int k = 0;
        }
     }
```

It's Access.

Comment: On Monday, the delivery of the course project. This is very urgent. Please help me

Comment: There's the chance that your database file is set to `Copy Always` instead of `Copy if newer` in its `Copy to Output Directory` property, so it's overwritten each time you start the application. Inspect it in Solution Explorer (assuming your procedure actually works).

Comment: the property was set initially

Comment: I'm like always. I asked the question myself, I answered it myself. If someone also happens, you need to run the program from the Debug folder when editing the database. Otherwise, the addition, editing, and deletion will occur with the wrong database file. I got to this point, using the method of scientific poke.

Comment: Are you by any chance using SQL Server and have `AttachDbFilename` in the connections string?

Comment: No, it's MS Access/

Answer (score 0):

I'm like always. I asked the question myself, I answered it myself. If someone also happens, you need to run the program from the Debug folder when editing the database. Otherwise, the addition, editing, and deletion will occur with the wrong database file. I got to this point, using the method of scientific poke.

Comment: Do you know why this happens? When you connect a database to a project, a small window appears: Copy the database to a local folder? Here is NO need to click. Enrages